# Python substring find

Tags: python-3.x, search, find, python-re

I'v a little request for you, I need help on this code:

```
def grepi(dico, fichier):
    line_number = 0
    nameFile = os.path.basename(fichier)
    # Chargement dico
    with open(dico, encoding="utf-8") as dic:
        dicolist = dic.read().splitlines()


    # Recherche dans fichier
    with open(fichier, encoding="utf-8") as fic:
        ficlist = fic.read().splitlines()

    for line in ficlist:
        line_number += 1
        for patt in dicolist:
            line = line.lower()
            if re.search(r' + line + r'\b', patt):
                print(line.rstrip() + ', ' + patt + ', ' + nameFile + ', '
                      + str(line_number))
```

I'v trouble here:  `if re.search(r' + line + r'\b', patt):`

`dico` is a dictionnary of first names like:

```
benoît
Nicolas
Stéphane
Sébastien
Alexandre
```

`fichier` is a file that contains a lot of information like:

```
Is the first name of Nicolas
Is Benoît is here
Hey 1234Alexandre1234
   Stéphane found something
dfqklnflSébastiendsqjfldsjfldksj
```

etc..

In the file I want to return all the exact strings (which are first names). But some names are formatted like this: 1234Alexandre5678 and the i don't find a way to return just the `Alexandre`, same thing for dfqklnflSébastiendsqjfldsjfldksj where i want to return `Sébastien`...

Can someone help me?
Thanks !

How I correct my code with the answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import re


def grepi(dico, fichier):
    line_number = 0
    nameFile = os.path.basename(fichier)
    result_final = []

    dicolist = open(dico, encoding="utf-8").read().splitlines()
    print(dicolist)

    with open(fichier, encoding="utf-8") as ficlist:
        ficstring = ficlist.read().splitlines()
        for line in ficstring:
            ptrn = re.compile(r"\w*(" + "|".join(dicolist) + r")\w*",
                              flags=re.I)
            ptrn_result = ptrn.findall(line)
            if ptrn_result:
                result_final = (nameFile, line_number, str(ptrn.findall(line)))
                print(result_final)
            line_number += 1
```

Here the output:

```
('prénom.xml', 4, "['Benoit']")
('prénom.xml', 6, "['Stéphane']")
('prénom.xml', 9, "['Alexandre']")
('prénom.xml', 10, "['Nicolas']")
('prénom.xml', 14, "['Sébastien']")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using pattern `'\w*(benoît|Nicolas|Stéphane|Sébastien|Alexandre)\w*'`

**Ex:**

```
import re

dicolist = ['benoît', 'Nicolas', 'Stéphane', 'Sébastien', 'Alexandre']
s = """Is the first name of Nicolas
Is Benoît is here
Hey 1234Alexandre1234
   Stéphane found something
dfqklnflSébastiendsqjfldsjfldksj"""

ptrn = re.compile(r"\w*(" + "|".join(dicolist) + r")\w*", flags=re.I)
print(ptrn.findall(s))
```

**Output:**

```
['Nicolas', 'Benoît', 'Alexandre', 'Stéphane', 'Sébastien']
```

Comment: I love this code! So I modified the script quite a bit accordingly to adapt it to my needs with your code. But it works! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Oh! Buddy, you first function grepi () needs some indentation. And the rest issues are quite complicated to myself too.

Comment: I am sorry! I pasted the code too quickly and forgot to indent it ...